# What's the algorithm (and its complexity) implemented in string::find found in LLVM libc++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, llvm, libc++

What's the algorithm (and its complexity) implemented in string::find method from LLVM libc++ (for C++ 11) distributed with Xcode? I can't find any documentation about that and following the library headers isn't very easy. Can anyone help?

Comment: I found [source code](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2014-May/034121.html) (I think).

Comment: The complexity of `std::string::find` is mandated by the standard (or, at least, its upper-bound is) so you can simply look that bit up. As for the actual algorithm .. who cares?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, I don't think the standard specifies anything about the complexity of `basic_string`'s `find`.

Comment: Actually, the standard says: "Unspecified, but generally up to linear in length()-pos times the length of the sequence to match (worst case)". Anyway, I was comparing the performance of Rust and C++ and it turned out that the C++'s algorithm is much better. I'm wondering what is the algorithm then.

Comment: Nothing particularly special. It essentially uses the same algorithm as `std::search`.

Comment: @jpw the trait's `find` isn't the same as `basic_string`'s. The latter isn't specified to use the former.

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: can you provide the location for that "Unspecified, but generally..." quote?  I can't find it.

Comment: @michaelBurr http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: @MichałFronczyk cplusplus.com isn't the standard, and it's got enough other problems that I don't suggest using it.

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: How are you comparing Rust's and C++'s string matchers?  Did you bother trying a bad case for either algorithm?

Comment: @T.C., cplusplus.com isn't the standard but I think it's good enough for the language users and it's much simpler to read/search.

Comment: @tmyklebu, I generated 10000 random UTF-8 strings of length between 20-120 containing ASCII and Polish letters and I generated 1000 random UTF-8 search patterns of 2-12 length using the same character set. Then I was trying to find each of the patterns in each of the random strings 5 times. BTW, I found out that Rust's str_find implementation is broken - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16878

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: It appears that Rust uses two-way string matching while `string::find` uses naive string matching.  Two-way matching takes linear time and constant additional space, while naive matching can take quadratic time.  It is trivial to find cases on which `string::find` exhausts your patience while Rust's string matching appears to return instantly.  Random cases **will not** do this.

Comment: @tmyklebu, you're right, but I think it's better to have a function that performs better in the average/most often case in the standard library than one that performs well only in the pessimistic case.

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: That's how you wind up with a string matcher that's only usable for trivial strings.

Comment: @tmyklebu Agreed. But I wanted to benchmark my target use case - checking for occurrence of a word (typical words are just several characters long) in a longer text. Maybe they could include 2 matchers in the API...

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: Yeah, there you want a naive matcher.  But naive matchers are real easy to write and two-way is not.

Comment: @tmyklebu, the naive matcher isn't that easy to write when you want it to perform very fast - see the C++ implementation mentioned below.

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: "Simpler" != "Correct"

Comment: @MichałFronczyk: The C++ implementation is a mess because it's in an implementation of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is their `basic_string`'s `find` (only one overload posted):

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::size_type
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::find(const value_type* __s,
                                                size_type __pos,
                                                size_type __n) const _NOEXCEPT
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__n == 0 || __s != nullptr, "string::find(): received nullptr");
    return _VSTD::__str_find<value_type, size_type, traits_type, npos>
        (data(), size(), __s, __pos, __n);
}
```

As can be seen, this just dispatches to the helper function `__str_find`, which performs some simple checks and then calls the helper function `__search` in [`<algorithm>`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm):

```
template<class _CharT, class _SizeT, class _Traits, _SizeT __npos>
_SizeT _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
__str_find(const _CharT *__p, _SizeT __sz, 
       const _CharT* __s, _SizeT __pos, _SizeT __n) _NOEXCEPT
{
    if (__pos > __sz || __sz - __pos < __n)
        return __npos;
    if (__n == 0)
        return __pos;
    const _CharT* __r = 
        _VSTD::__search(__p + __pos, __p + __sz,
                        __s, __s + __n, _Traits::eq,
                        random_access_iterator_tag(), random_access_iterator_tag());
    if (__r == __p + __sz)
        return __npos;
    return static_cast<_SizeT>(__r - __p);
}
```

It's worth noting that `__search` is also the function called by `std::search`:

```
template <class _ForwardIterator1, class _ForwardIterator2, class _BinaryPredicate>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_ForwardIterator1
search(_ForwardIterator1 __first1, _ForwardIterator1 __last1,
       _ForwardIterator2 __first2, _ForwardIterator2 __last2, _BinaryPredicate __pred)
{
    return _VSTD::__search<typename add_lvalue_reference<_BinaryPredicate>::type>
                         (__first1, __last1, __first2, __last2, __pred,
                          typename std::iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator1>::iterator_category(),
                          typename std::iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator2>::iterator_category());
}
```

The implementation of `__search` itself is fairly standard, with a manually unrolled loop if `!_LIBCPP_UNROLL_LOOPS` is zero. You can find it in the `<algorithm>` header linked above.

Comment: How did you find out what file _VSTD refers to?

Comment: @MichałFronczyk `_VSTD` is a macro, referring to the namespace in which libc++'s functions are defined. The actual definition is compiler-dependent, and can be found in [`__config`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__config).

Comment: So it's quadratic?  It doesn't punt to `memmem`?

Comment: @tmyklebu I'm doubtful that it can use `memmem` even if it wanted to. (The comparison is specified to use `traits::eq`).

Comment: Eeeeeugh.  Gross.  Kids, this is how you paint yourself into a corner at design time.

Answer (score 0):

according to the cplusplus.com:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Complexity:
Unspecified, but generally up to linear in length()-pos times the length of the sequence to match (worst case).

I do not think there a special algorithms for string matching implemented in libcxx (c++ lib llvm links against).
If you search the source code in libcxx SVN repository for "find", you only obtain hints to debug.cpp.

So the complexity is that of the naive search algorithm. If you need special algorithms like Knut-Morris-Pratt etc. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) have a look at boosts implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't agree with you. There is a lot of "find" occurrences in "algorithm" and "string" header files there.

Comment: Why did you assert citing cppreference.com but link to cplusplus.com?